# TeamCIty Branch Specification Wildcard Syntax (Git)

Tags: git, teamcity

What syntax is available to me to be able to filter the branches in the Branch Specification?

My branches are mostly named like....

```
 refs/heads/main-featureX
```

...but there are some like...

```
 refs/heads/main-featureX-blah
```

I want to include the branches like the first example, but the not the ones like the second, but with only one '*' wildcard allowed I don't seem to be able to do that.  e.g.

```
+:refs/heads/main-feature*
```

...is kind of ok as a start, but I then want to further exclude branches with the second '-', something along the lines of...

```
-:refs/heads/main-feature*-*
```

...but that doesn't seem to be possible because I can only use one '*' wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's not much you can do using TeamCity branch specification syntax here. However, you might slightly change your branch naming scheme by adding some prefix(es) to the branch names you want being monitored by TeamCity; then you could use specifications like

```
+:refs/heads/2test-*
+:refs/heads/ci/*
```

or just the opposite, like

```
-:refs/heads/do-not-test/*
-:refs/heads/unstable-*
```

or kinda combination of them. It seems like the first approach requires less changes in the branch structure, if any.

Comment: This is more or less what we had to do, although due to some complications filtering exactly what we wanted, we found it easier to use a suffix of '-CI', which seems to be working quite well.